# What are the licence restrictions for the RxTx Library

Tags: java, licensing, serial-port, lgpl

I want to make an Application that uses [RxTx](http://users.frii.com/jarvi/rxtx/index.html) version 2.2pre2 to work with Serial Ports. What are the Licence restrictions, since it is an "LGPL v 2.1 + Linking Over Controlled Interface" licenced library if I don't use the Sun's javax.comm.* interface, but the RxTx's own gnu.io.* when importing into Java Files?

Comment: You might be interested in my alternative library (Apache license): http://code.google.com/p/jperipheral/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From using RXTX in the past my understanding is that if you are using the gnu.io interfaces directly then the standard LGPL licensing terms will apply.